# change font button swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

in my playground I need to change the font of text in the button, how can I do? This is my code to declare the button in the playground

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 133.4))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
```

Answer (score -1):

`button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Times New Roman", size: 20)`